# insert associaitve array though model CI

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in the following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [31] => Battery Diagnostic
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [31] => Spare Tire Installation
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [31] => ABS Light is on Inspection
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [31] => Air filter is clogged Inspection
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [31] => Adjust Windshield Washer Jets
        )

)
```

this is my model

```
function services_get_a_quote($data){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";

        foreach ($data as $key => $item){
            //$this->db->insert("services_get_a_quote",$data[]=array("key"=>"value"));
            echo  $key;//prints ok
            echo  $item['Array']; //prints error
        }

    }
```

i wan to generate a query to insert both keys and values into db through  loop because this array has a foreign key and a value associated with it!
now i have been over this issue for a while now i cant seem to get the value of the array e.g `Battery Diagnostic` 
where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Try this `echo current($item);`

Comment: what is current?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Comment: [Current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

Comment: It will return the current element from array

Comment: it is returning the whole value whereas i want the key and value attribute inside value attribute of whole array separately because they are basically db columns so i need them separately

Comment: basically i want [31] and [Battery Diagnostic] in two separate variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) functions of array

Please check the below code:

```
function services_get_a_quote($data){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    foreach ($data as $key => $item){

        echo  $key;//prints ok
        echo  reset($item); // returns value
        echo  key($item); // returns key
    }

}
```

You can save to different var as per your need.

`reset($item)` will give first element of array

and `key()` is used for getting current key of array